# LM338T Output to 5V issue with LM1085-IT 3.3V

Tags: voltage-regulator, 5v, lm317, 3.3v, lm78xx

I am using 12V , 2A DC power supply as an input to LM338T and LM1085-IT 3.3 , for 5V and 3.3V output respectively.

The issue i am facing here is when these both voltage regulators are connected in the circuit , LM338T only gives 1.26V output , which is expected as 5V and LM1085-IT gives 3.3V output (which is correct as expected ).

When i disconnect the ground wire between the 12v ground and LM1085-IT 3.3v regulator , the LM338T gives proper 5v but when this ground wire is connected it gives only 1.26V.

Capacitors are connected as given in the datasheet of LM338T, but have not shown in my image.

Please guide me , i am a newbie in electronics and lacking to solve it.

Here i am attaching the image of the connections.

[image]

Comment: Where are your caps?

Comment: they are connected. haven't shown here in the image.

Comment: THen edit the question and use the schematic editor at the top of the editor to show a real schematic... How is anyone supposed to answer this when you only give half the information......

Comment: Apology. This schematic is what i could prepare.
Question Edited Too.
Please Guide.

Comment: Your schematic shows measuring the 5V output between OUT and ADJ. it should be between OUT and the negative of the input voltage (ground).

Comment: @DoxyLover : showing 2.30v according to your suggestion.

Comment: In short, the hook-up of LM338 is completely wrong. Please see Datasheet for proper connections and recommended resistor values.

Comment: @AliChen : Actually i searched google to calculate R1 & R2, with the help of those websites i chose the available resistors.
But when i disconnect the ground wire of power supply and lm1085 3.3 , the LM338 gives me proper 4.96V output.
Please give your suggestions to make the proper connections.

Comment: Proper suggestions are shown in Fig.16 of LM338T datasheet.

Comment: @AliChen : Thanks for helping so fast. I really appreciate it.
I will check it with fig16 and get back soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LM338T regulator is a very old design, and it has very substantial "adjustment" current, 50 uA. As such, the feedback circuit has to be of relatively low impedance. Check with [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm338.pdf) and application diagram on page 12, it needs about 820 Ohm and 270 Ohm resistors to operate properly.

Comment: Actually i searched on google to calculate the R1 and R2 on couple of websites, Hence used the available resistor values. 
But if i disconnect the ground wire of power supply and LM1085 3.3 , the LM338T is giving me proper 4.96V output.

Comment: @KarmaCoding, apparently you used wrong Google sources for your calculations. The correct resistor values are 270 Ohms instead of "green 51k", and 820 Ohms instead of 15k. Manufacturer's datasheet always should be trusted first against Internet hackings.

Comment: Thanks for helping so fast. I really appreciate it.
I will check it with fig16 and get back soon.

Comment: @KarmaCoding, you should be checking with Fig.16 15 mins ago :-)  And keep in mind that the regulator is designed to produce 5V (with 270/820 Ohm divider) between **common GROUND** (negative terminal of your 12-V source) and OUTPUT. You need to correct your diagram and measuring method.

Comment: Seems like a newbie in electronics like me have a lot things to learn.
thanks for the response.

Comment: It worked. it is giving proper output now.
by using 820 and 270 ohm. 
I want to ask one more question if u can help me out here.
I am using LM1085-IT 3.3 to to power NODEMCU. my power supply has 3A CAPACITY AND LM1085-IT 3.3 too have the same 3A Capacity. The LM1085-IT 3.3 is getting over heated.
The thing i am not be able to understand it why is it getting heated , does NODEMCU uses great amount of current or is there any other reason.

Comment: @KarmaCoding, who is "NODEMCU"? The LM1085 overheats likely because is has to dissipate heat from 12-3 = 9 V times whatever current it delivers. If it is more than 100 mA, the regulator would need a heat sink of some sort.

Comment: heatsink i am using right now.
I generally wanted to know the reason of heating.
I think i need to study more on this.
Btw thanks for the help and guidance.
Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Ground wire for your "Point B" should connect to the negative side of the 12 volt supply, not to the LM338 ADJ terminal.  The LKM338 attempts to maintain about 1.25 volts between ADJ and OUT terminals.

Comment: I connected according to your suggestion , then it is showing 2.30v at POINT B.